# Who is הרב הנאמ"ן?

Tags: halacha, rabbis

I was learning the sefer אור ההלכה on hilchos Shabbos and he quotes someone as הרב הנאמ"ן. Does anyone know who that is?

Comment: There are a lot of sefarim with that name. Who is the author?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rav Meir Mazuz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Mazuz) (הרב מאיר נסים מאזוז).

The name is based on his signature נאמ״ן ס״ט = נאום אנכי מאיר נסים, סיפיה טב.